# Чи правильно казати "термоусадка"

Tags: терміни, росіянізм

Слово *термоусадка* має вигляд кальки з російської, але українського відповідника я не знайшов. У словнику української мови слова *термоусадка* немає, натомість є слово [усадка](http://sum.in.ua/s/usadka), яке доволі чітко відображає зміст

http://sum.in.ua/s/usadka

Пошуковик google видає [117 000](https://tinyurl.com/2p8zvtv7) результатів за запитом "термоусадка -и", тобто лише з україномовних сторінок. Хоча така кількість сторінок це скоріше автоматичний переклад з російської, а не ознака правильного відповідника

Тож питання, чи правильно в українській мові користуватися словом *термоусадка*? Якщо ні, то який відповідник найкраще використовувати?

Answer (score 4):

**Термоусадка** це **heat-shrink tubing** англійською
Серед значень **shrink** є вираз **давати усадку**

Тож русізм **термоусадка** також є цілком коректним і для української

UPD:
Виробники ще інколи використовують варіант **термозбіжна трубка**
Можливо, з часом, в промисловому жаргоні зʼявиться відповідне скорочення

Comment: Тут варто подумати чи варто вживати слово *усадка*. СУМ усе-таки писали в радянському союзі. [Раніші словники](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) такого слова не знають.

Comment: а ось гуглопереклад з польської дає цікавіший вариант: termokurczka -> термозбіжна трубка

Comment: Дякую, це дійсно хороший варіант. Теж думав про нього.

Comment: Дякую. Термозбіжна трубка дійсно цікавий варіант. Хоча термоусадка передає сенс одним словом, думаю вона має більше шансів вкорінитися в мові

Comment: Термозбіжка як варіант :) Але все ж слова можуть по інерції зберігатись у суспільстві.

Answer (score 2):

Почнімо зі слова "усадка". Як згадали в іншому коментарі, таке слово зустрічається в СУМ-11, проте радянський СУМ аж ніяк не можна вважати за хороше джерело питомості слів. Особливо слів будівничої словниці. У старіших словника слова "усадка" не зустрічаємо, й навіть сучасні словники дають московському "усадка" інші переклади вкраїнською. Тож робимо висновок і не маємо сумнівів, шо слово саме московське. Морфологічно, фонетично, та, мабуть, семантично цілком можливе слово й для вкраїнської, проте таки черпане з московської.

Інша справа, котра мені меляє, це слово "термоусадка" та його фонетична невідповідність у вкраїнській мові. Хоч маємо купу сучасних слів, де зівом голосних знехтувано ("авіаудар", до прикаладу), та не маємо права вважати то за шось добре. "Чергування" у-в у вкраїнській мові це річ фонотактична, де втворюється збіг голосних, там /в/ здобуває нескладотвірність. Хилю до того, шо вкраїнською фонетично правильний твар мав би бути "термовсадка", де <в> здійснено як [u̯], з нескладотворчою вимовою префікса "у-" (у-сад-(ь)ка).